# Django: multiple dates form

Tags: django, django-models, weather-api

so in my .html file i inserted two inputs for two different dates (end and start)

```
From: <input type='date' name='fromdate'/>
To: <input type='date' name='todate'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
```

and in my models.py i have this model

```
class MyDatesInput(models.Model):
dates = ArrayField(models.DateTimeField() )
```

i need to use the dates for an api call like this:

```
http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&type=hour&start={start}&end={end}&appid={API key}
```

how do i link all of this together?

Comment: `MyDatesInput.dates` just contains two dates for the start/end and you're using postgresql? Use a DateRangeField instead? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield

Comment: it was one of the solutions that i found, does DateRangeField suit better for the purpose?

Comment: I would say so, a range suits a start and end date better than an array